# Change JButtons Names and use the new Name. in methods

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, local-variables

I have a swing java application on which I have a 114 button

I have created the buttons by a loop

```
 Container pane = getContentPane();
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 JButton b; 
 for(int i=1;i<115;i++)

  {

   b = new JButton(""+i);
   panel.add(b);
    }
```

So all buttons will take the name b   !!!

that is the problem here
 I want to give each button  a different  name  to execute different action for each button.
by ActionListener class

```
        JButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your buttons don't have the name `b`. You are using a local variable `b` inside the for loop. You can for instance create an array of buttons and store your `JButton` instances there. Later, you can loop through that array to change the buttons text.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add your buttons to a Map using what you want to call the button as the key. Then you can access the button by calling the get() on the Map with whatever you want to call the button.